# Controlling authorization/scope in a web application

Tags: web-applications, authorization

Every discussion or tutorial I've ever come across about authorization has only dealt with simple binary authorization.  In a blogging application, can the user edit pages? Can the user approve comments?  Simple examples like that.

What I haven't seen a lot of is more complex "scope"-based authorization examples.  Can the user edit *this* page?  Can the user approve *this* comment?  ...where the user has permission to perform actions on certain records, but not all.

Are there common approaches to this problem? Any good examples?  I can whip up various simple solutions, but I hate feeling like I'm reinventing the wheel.

FWIW, the current application I'm dealing with is build in Python Pylons.

Comment: This is a good question. But I think it always depends mainly on problem domain. I mean problem domains can differ so much that I wouldn't expect you can find any universally "best" approach in a book. For example look at this stackoverflow site - do you think they did this great work after reading about it in a book? Think again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive seen it done 2 ways:

1. In a rich-domain model, the object being changed can do the security check (the object could be put into a read-only mode when the user was not authorized to edit it, and would throw an exception otherwise, for example).
2. In an anemic-domain model, the check is done by the service operating on the object (or a collaborating security service).

Both approaches required work.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I run across this once in a while. You can take a look and see if Python has something similar to GACL that PHP has. But that might be overkill.

If you run across this a lot, I'd implement an ACL and just reuse it. Granted you are using the same framework.